# If the universe is closed, does that also mean time is closed?

Tags: universe, curvature, topology, closed-timelike-curve

Speaking just about space, we say that the universe is either open (topologically $E^3$) or closed (topologically $S^3$). But since a metric connection defines curvature on *spacetime* and not just space, does this mean a closed universe (having positive curvature) is also a closed spacetime (topologically $S^4$)? In other words, would positive curvature with a closed universe imply that we are on a closed time-like curve? Otherwise, spacetime would be open (topologically $E^4$ or $S^3\times E^1$) even if space is closed.

Answer (score 1):

No. For example, in the [Friedmann metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) with $k=+1$, space is closed but timelike curves in spacetime are not closed.